# How can i use regular expression with assertions in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, assertions

My website is available in multiple languages including English and French. I am using JMeter for testing and want to make sure that a certain phrase is available regardless of the language.

Is there a way to **assert via JMeter** that a phrase (for example "Login") is **available regardless of the language in use**, for example by using regular expressions?

Comment: The essence of the question seems not to be the use of regular expressions but in general the language-independent assertion so I tried to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This will of course largely depend on how the language for your service is determined. It might be through Geo-IP (in which case testing it is going to be difficult), cookies or the [Accept-Language HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Accept-Language).

You could just run different tests with multiple different cookies/Accept-Language headers and then just look for the Login string with the typical JMeter assertions.

Comment: i ahve externalized my script such a way that it is not language dependent but if same script we will run for different language then assertion will fail as in main script assertions are set in english so if we want to execute same test for french what is the best way to set assertions so it does not fail no matter which language are we running against

Comment: That is just not possible.